# How do you apply a custom median filter with threshold?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, median

I am trying to create a custom median filter for my image processing where for a 3x3 neighbourhood, the central pixel (being changed) is excluded. My kernel is therefore

```
 1     1     1
 1     0     1
 1     1     1
```

But I want to only change the central pixel to the median of the surrounding pixels if its value deviates by more than the surrounding pixels by some threshold value. E.g. if the pixel is more than 10 times the median of the surrounding pixels, then the central pixel value is changed to the median.

I've looked at using ordfilt2 and I can create a median filter with it. But I am not sure how I can implement the threshold condition. I am essentially trying to remove any outliers within my image which meet the threshold condition within my kernel.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: It's not answer... But I'd be tempted to evade the question, comparing against the median of the entire 3x3.This gives a similar but different result, sometimes more biased towards preserving the central pixel. For hot pixel removal it should work fine. It also avoids the awkwardness of defining a median of an even number of items.

Comment: I see what you mean Nick. However, I actually just chose 3x3 as a simple example. My actual kernel size would be much larger in practice where the median of the kernel is likely to be different from the pixel value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have a single function for doing that, but `ord2filt` is a good start.

```
N = uint8([1 1 1 ; 1 0 1 ; 1 1 1]);   % neighborhood, faster with integer class
J = (ordfilt2(I,4,N) + ordfilt2(I,5,N))/2;   % median of even set
M = I>J+10;    % put here your threshold method
Out = I;
Out(M) = J(M);
```

Rem: question already asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1756690/creating-holey-median-filter-in-matlab?rq=1), but without any good answer IMO.

Comment: This method works perfectly and is really simple to implement. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

I suggest the following approach:

```
%defines input
A = repmat(1:5,5,1);

%step 1: median filtering, ignoring the central pixel
fun = @(x) median([x(1:ceil(length(x(:))/2-1)),x(ceil(length(x(:))/2+1):end)]);
filteredA = nlfilter(A,[3 3],fun);

%step 2: changing each pixel, onlyt if its 10 times bigger from the median
result = A;
changeMask = (A./filteredA)>10 | (A./filteredA)<0.1;
result(changeMask ) = filteredA(changeMask);
```